How do I clean and maintain my silver jewelry to prevent tarnishing?
I have several pieces of silver jewelry that have started to tarnish, and I want to keep them looking shiny and new. I'm looking for effective cleaning methods and maintenance tips to prevent further tarnishing. What are the best practices for cleaning and caring for silver jewelry to maintain its luster?

Hi Vinni, what have you tried so far? Can you post a picture of the jewellery? (Your profile links to a jewellery website - please don't try to post spam, because it's just extra work for both parties and will get you your profile deleted.)

@Joachim: the description of her profile is in strong opposition with the content of the question. Either she is knowledgeable and "top" and experienced, or she does not know to use a piece of cloth to make silver shiny - and then cover it with any transparent lacquer .

@virolino True, it's unlikely to be a genuine question, but as it stands it's perfectly fitting for the site. It could be the start of a self-answered question, in which expert knowledge is passed along. And it allows for genuine answers all the same.
